# PHP-Interbase : Product Interbase is Not Licensed

Tags: php, ms-access, interbase

I have a services create with PHP PDO for Data Transfer from Fingerscan Machine that uses Ms.Access (.MDB) to Internal Application that uses Interbase 2009 (.BI)

Currently the services are running well and getting data every 3 minutes.
But i have one problem that occurs with Interbase Licensing.

I don't know exactly when the error occurs, but i think every 2 or 3 days, i getting error "Product INTERBASE is not licensed" . But after i restarting the IB Console and refresh the webpage, its back to normal.

I have tried to search any solutions, but there are no one match with the PHP-Interbase case.

Thanks for your attention and answer

Comment: Do you have a valid license for INTERBASE?  Has the license been appropriately unlocked where INTERBASE is installed?

Comment: On the server, the Interbase are have valid license. But i install IB Console "Client Only" on another server which installed Fingerscan Machine software. So the PHP file can connecting to Interbase Server.

Comment: maybe worth seeking technical help from the provider itself? They might know better about their own software piece.